# SSH into EC2 instance while it is running a script

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance that I am using to populate a database. I have a python script that I run by entering:
`nohup python populate_db.py &`. This works and the database starts getting populated. However, if I leave the ssh session and then try to rejoin as this is running I get the following output when adding the `vvv` flag:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
[xx.xxx.xxx.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/ec2key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/ec2key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Additionally my cloudwatch logs seem to stop recording, and the CPU usage after spiking to a maximum of 80% drops down to around 6% usage, so it feels like something might be crashing.

Is there a way to figure out what is going wrong/fix this?

Comment: Try using `screen` instead of `nohup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my script had a memory leak in it. I didn't have memory monitoring over on EC2, but running it locally the memory in use climbed to 2.5 GB within a few minutes (much more than the t2.micro can handle).